# Is there an efficient way to sort packed strings in PHP?

Tags: php, ipv6, processing-efficiency

I have a PHP application which needs to store IPv6 addresses in sorted order. I have written a comparison operation for IPv6 addresses which uses "inet" and "gmp" library functions, but I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this - ideally by operating directly on the 16 byte packed string representation of the IPv6 address. Is there a convenient way to do this (without compiling a custom PHP extension)?

*EDIT:* I'm interested in both *time* and *space* efficiency, here, which is why I'm attracted by the idea of using a packed string representation. And although I'm aware that there are fancy trie-based representations of IPv6 sets used by routers to optimize certain search operations, I'm not asking for references to any C libraries or research papers in this question. I'm asking specifically about sorting in PHP, which is quite different from sorting in C, Perl, or Python. The number of address to be managed is < 100 million, but more than 1 million.

Comment: Just curious - why is it important that they are sorted? What are you trying to do that needs them to be in a sorted list? How many addresses are you thinking of keeping in this sorted list? Actually for fast access to  sorted lists - have you looked at a 'local' redis database? Just a random thought.

Comment: @HalayemAnis, why would the direction of sorting matter? If I can do one way I can do the other.

Comment: @RyanVincent, the context here is code for manipulating contiguous blocks of IPv6 addresses, which may be represented as "ordered pairs" (or endpoints), which are easiest to search if they are kept sorted. I'm not interested in a survey of IPv6 routing implementations in other languages, or in memory databases like redis either - unless they have some amazingly efficient tech specifically for manipulating arbitrary sets of IPv6 addresses. What I'm interested in right now is the problem of storing and sorting these addresses efficiently in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your requirements. How large are these blocks of addresses and how many addresses in total - a rough estimate will be useful. And how do  want to search them? by ip address to find the other endpoint? IP Pairs for existing? Other functions? Just curious. The size of the dataset that you expect to use has an impact on the answers that you will find useful.

Comment: @RyanVincent, I updated the original question with a rough guess as to the number of IPv6 addresses (between 1 and 100 million). The distribution is likely to be varied - some singletons and some ranges, some large ranges and some small. There may be long shared prefixes on some cases, and not in others.

Comment: If you used them as the primary key in a database then as there is a couple of GB of data in the worse case and they would be kept sorted. You would need to run some queries to generate lists of blocks that you held in other tables. I wouldn't have thought it that slow. Just a thought.

Comment: @RyanVincent By "them" you mean what, the left edge of an address range? And by "other tables" you mean what exactly? Perhaps you're missing the point of the question, which specifically about *how* to do the sorting efficiently, not whether or not sorting is required.

Comment: What happened when you tried [the obvious solution](http://www.php.net/sort)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton If you represent IPv6 addresses as strings of decimal digits, then PHP sort() will apply lexicographical sorting (which is wrong because 20 is larger than 9). You cannot represent IPv6 integers as positive integers in PHP because they are too big. So as indicated in my original question I wrote a comparison operation (which works on packed string representations of IPv6 addresses), which can be used with usort() (or uksort()) and this works as desired. But it isn't as fast as I would like it to be, hence the question.

Comment: If you were storing packed binary data, then sort() and its friends ought to work just fine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Indeed! So why not answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Michael Hampton in the comments, sort() and ksort() ought to work just fine on packed strings. Here's a script to demonstrate:

```
<?php

if (defined('AF_INET6')) {
    echo "PHP was compiled without --disable-ipv6 option";
} else {
    echo "PHP was compiled with --disable-ipv6 option";
}

$a = array(
    inet_pton('::1'),
    inet_pton('1::'),
    inet_pton('::a'),
    inet_pton('a::'),
    inet_pton('20::'),
    inet_pton('::20'),
    inet_pton('9::'),
    inet_pton('::9')
);

print "\nbefore sort:\n";
foreach ($a as $r) { print inet_ntop($r) . "\n"; flush(); }

sort($a);

print "\nafter sort:\n";
foreach ($a as $r) { print inet_ntop($r) . "\n"; flush(); }
```

When I run this in my development environment, I get the following output, which is correct:

```
PHP was compiled without --disable-ipv6 option
before sort:
::1
1::
::a
a::
20::
::20
9::
::9

after sort:
::1
::9
::a
::20
1::
9::
a::
20::
```

So the Good News appears to be that inet_pton(), inet_ntop(), sort(), and ksort() will "just work" the way I want them to.

This makes me happy. And surprised, in a Good Way, by PHP!

**EDIT:** There appears to be a [bug in inet_pton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905707/is-inet-pton-broken-for-some-ipv6-addresses-that-look-like-ipv4-addresses) which complicates the use of Michael Hampton's "obvious" approach. Fortunately, there are ways to work around it.

Comment: The most important part is the realisation that in the chosen representation your most significant bytes come first and therefore the standard string comparison will work as expected :)

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer, here, since Michael Hampton did not officially offer one.

Comment: RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952), discusses the problem of sorting and searching IPv6 addresses, and provides the standards-based recommendations to assist with this.

Comment: @RonMaupin, section 4 of this RFC recommends a "standard" way to write IPv6 addresses as colon-separated hexwords, but isn't really relevant to my question at all. The RFC mentions searching only to point out that a simple text search for IPv6 addresses will fail if there is ambiguity in the text representation (hence the need for the proposed standard), and doesn't even mention sorting once.

Comment: @Peter, taken as a whole, the RFC does help with sorting and searching. As the RFC points out, uppercase and lowercase letters have different values (2001:a:: actually comes after 2001:FFFF::). Both searching and sorting are simplified when following the RFC where it says you MUST use lowercase letters. While the RFC may not directly mention sorting, it does benefit sorting IPv6 addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin, I agree that the RFC helps with text searching, but not sorting (which again is the point of my question). If you try to sort IPv6 addresses (regardless of whether the RFC recommendations are followed) as text strings, you will find 20:: comes before 9::. If you want a sortable representation you have to use something else. And packed strings work nicely, as it turns out!

Comment: As discussed in your other question, that's not a bug. And it won't affect any real world usage anyway, even if it does break your demonstration script.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I disagree on both counts. Although ::/96 may be deprecated and ::ffff/96 is mandated, I think it is reasonable to expect the PHP inet_ntop() function to treat all addresses in ::/96 the same way (and they are not). And I have a "real world" PHP 5.2.17 application requiring IPv6 address arithmetic, but gmp_import() and gmp_export() aren't available until PHP 5.6.1, so I need a way to convert the packed string IPv6 representation into a (potentially very large) number. A well-behaved inet_ntop() function would make this much easier.