# Is inet_pton() broken for some IPv6 addresses that "look like" IPv4 addresses?

Tags: php, ipv6

I'm using PHP version 5.2.17, and I see that the following works as expected:

```
$x = inet_pton('::F');
$y = inet_ntop($x);
print "::F -> $y\n";

Output: ::F -> ::f
```

But the following does not:

```
$a = inet_pton('::FEEF:1886');
$b = inet_ntop($a);
print "::FEEF:1886 -> $b\n";

Output: ::FEEF:1886 -> ::254.239.24.134
```

I would have expected the second code snippet to produce this output:

```
::FEEF:1886 -> ::feef:1886
```

What is it about the IPv6 address ::FEEF:1886 that makes PHP think it is really an IPv4 address? The inet_ntop/inet_pton conversion works correctly with other addresses having 0 in the "high" 96 bits (e.g. ::F).

***EDIT:*** My first thought was that this might be a bug in my version of PHP, but using [this online PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) I see the same behavior for PHP versions up through 5.6.2. So either this is deliberate (in which case I would dearly like to know the reason for this behavior) or a bug which persists in modern versions of PHP.

***ADDENDUM:*** I opened [PHP Bug 69232](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69232) on March 12, 2015 for this apparent inconsistency in the behavior of inet_ntop() for addresses in ::/96.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers provided by kasperd, diskwuff, and JC Sama offer both helpful information and workarounds which are likely to be useful to other SO readers, so I have upvoted them all. But they do not address my original question directly, so I'm adding this answer:

**The behavior of the PHP function inet_pton() is correct. The problem is that inet_ntop() does not treat IPv6 address in ::/96 consistently. [This is a bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69232).**

Answer (score 3):

The textual representation of IPv6 addresses permit for multiple different valid representations of every IPv6 address.

This means that all of these valid textual representations of an IPv6 address each map to the same binary 128 bit string when passed through `inet_pton`.

However when converting the binary 128 bit string to textual representation using `inet_ntop`, it can obviously only output one of the many valid strings representing that IP address. The one it chose is called the canonical representation.

It is always valid to write the last 32 bits of an IPv6 address using IPv4 notation. However only a few classes of IPv6 addresses used that format as their canonical representation.

`::/96` has been deprecated, but that just means those addresses are not supposed to be used anymore, it doesn't affect how they are treated by `inet_pton` and `inet_ntop`.

`::ffff:0.0.0.0/96` is another prefix, which use IPv4 notation in their canonical representation. That prefix is used for IPv4 compatibility in the socket API, but those are never send on the wire, because they are for situations where the traffic on the wire will be IPv4.

Comment: That is all well and good (although [RFC 4291](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.5) indicates that IPv4 mapped IPv6 addresses are in the range ::FFFF/96). What puzzles me at this point is why PHP inet_pton() doesn't treat all /96 addresses the same way. +1 for calling out the canonical representation (although again it mystifies me why two different /96 addresses would have such different canonical representations).

Comment: @Peter Those two /96 use the IPv4 notation in their canonical representation because they are used for IPv4 backward compatibility, and in those cases the last part of the IPv6 address always is an IPv4 address. The reason there are two such /96 and not just one is that it took two attempts at deciding what that IPv4 compatibility should behave like, hence the first of the two has been deprecated.

Comment: RFC 4291 indicates that ::/96 are "IPv4-Compatible IPv6 Addresses", which are indeed deprecated, and ::ffff/96 are "IPv4-Mapped IPv6 Addresses", which are not. My point is simply that it is the behavior of the PHP inet_ntop() function for addresses in ::/96 is inconsistent - I should either be getting ::f and ::feef:1886, or ::0.0.0.15 and ::254.239.24.134.

Comment: @Peter You are right, that does indeed seem inconsistent. But IPv4-compatible IPv6 addresses do not cover all of ::/96. :: and ::1 have other uses. I haven't found any standard document specifying exactly how much of ::/96 are not IPv4-compatible IPv6 addresses. However since 0.0.0.0/8 is reserved, that means ::/104 cannot really be used as IPv4-compatible IPv6 addresses. So one would expect the line be drawn at either ::/104 or ::/127. For some reason it appears the line was drawn at ::/112, which seems a bit odd but shouldn't really break anything.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is an IPv4 address being represented (incorrectly) as an IPv6 address. This practice was officially deprecated in 2006 by [RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.5):

> The "IPv4-Compatible IPv6 address" is now deprecated because the
> current IPv6 transition mechanisms no longer use these addresses.
> New or updated implementations are not required to support this
> address type.

Comment: Thanks for the RFC link, which definitely helps put the problem in proper historical perspective. But if the PHP inet_ntop() function were to treat this "deprecated" case consistently, then *all* IPv4 addresses with the "top" 96 bits = 0 would be returned as IPv4 addresses with the double colon prefix, right? And yet ::F when converted to a packed string via inet_pton() and then converted back again via inet_ntop() to a printable string becomes ::f, not ::0.0.0.15. This makes me concerned that the PHP implementations of these functions is buggy.

Comment: PHP just uses the underlying C library. Both `::f` and `::0.0.0.15` are valid representations of the same IPv6 address. Showing the last 32 bits in IPv4 notation is an allowed but not mandatory feature. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952#section-5. I agree that for consistency it should show the IPv4 notation, even if the embedded IPv4 address is invalid/reserved/etc.

Comment: @Peter Keep in mind that 0.0.0.15 isn't really a valid IPv4 address; 0.0.0.0/8 is reserved. So I can't really fault `inet_pton()` for not knowing what to do with it.

Comment: @SanderSteffann, thanks for another fine link. And it is good to know I'm not alone in being surprised that PHP inet_ntop() doesn't at least use the same rule for preparing printable versions of all addresses in /96.

Comment: @duskwuff I know that 0/8 is reserved for broadcast, which means I cannot assign the IPv4 address 0.0.0.15 to a host for example. But it *is* a perfectly valid address, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
function _inet_ntop($ip) {

  if (strlen($ip) == 4) { // For IPv4
    list(, $ip) = unpack('N', $ip);
    $ip = long2ip($ip);
  }
  elseif(strlen($ip) == 16) { // For IPv6
    $ip = bin2hex($ip);
    $ip = substr(chunk_split($ip, 4, ':'), 0, -1);
    $ip = explode(':', $ip);
    $res = '';

    foreach($ip as $index => $seg) {
      while ($seg {0} == '0')
        $seg = substr($seg, 1);

      if ($seg != '') {
        $res .= $seg;
        if ($index < count($ip) - 1)
          $res .= $res == '' ? '' : ':';
      } else {
        if (strpos($res, '::') === false)
          $res .= ':';

      }
    }
    $ip = $res;
  }

  return $ip;
}
```

And you can call this function instead of `inet_ntop` :

```
$a = inet_pton('::FEEF:1886');
$b = _inet_ntop($a);
print "::FEEF:1886 -> $b\n";
// Output => ::FEEF:1886 -> ::feef:1886

$x = inet_pton('::F');
$y = _inet_ntop($x);
print "::F -> $y\n";
// Output => ::F -> ::f
```

Comment: Nice! My own workaround was to write a "wrapper" function for inet_ntop() which "notices" when the string representation ends with an IPv4 address string and converts it back to a couple of hex words (or one, or none, depending on whether there are leading zeros to be absorbed by the leading double colon). +1 for unpack() and bin2hex(). I'm still curious why the PHP inet_ntop() function doesn't treat all /96 address the same way, though.

Comment: I notice that applying your _inet_ntop() function to the packed string inet_pton('02a1:89ea:58bf:f4b2:0fd2:5631:0000:0000') gives 2a1:89ea:58bf:f4b2:fd2:5631: instead of 2a1:89ea:58bf:f4b2:fd2:5631:: (i.e. the terminal double colon is rendered as a single colon).

Comment: Yes, your new code works with all my test cases, but runs a bit slower than my own solution - which I guess I should publish here.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what I've head so far in the answers & comments:

- IPv6 addresses have a canonical format which is what inet_ntop() returns.
- The ::/96 address range is deprecated, but ::ffff/80 is not.
- Although it would make sense for *all* ::/96 addresses to be rendered as ::/IPv4-address by inet_ntop() it appears that inet_ntop() renders ::/112 addresses and "higher" in ::/96 as ::/IPv4-dotted-quad (e.g. ::254.239.24.134) and renders ::/96 addresses "lower" than ::/112 as "normal" IPv6 addresses.
- If you want inet_ntop() to render all IPv6 addresses the same way (i.e. 8 hex words with the usual zero compression rules) then you need to write your own method to achieve this.

My own workaround is to extend inet_ntop() by rewriting any IPv4 dotted quads as hexwords (and I exploded the logic into multiple methods to make it easier for me to keep track of what I was doing):

```
function _inet_ntop($addr) {
    return fix_ipv4_compatible_ipv6(inet_ntop($addr));
}

/**
 * If $str looks like ::/IPv4-dotted-quad then rewrite it as
 * a "pure" IPv6 address, otherwise return it unchanged.
 */
function fix_ipv4_compatible_ipv6($str) {
    if (
        ($str[0] == ':') &&
        ($str[1] == ':') &&
        preg_match('/^::(\S+\.\S+)$/', $str, $match)
    ) {
        $chunks = explode('.', $match[1]);
        return self::ipv4_zones_to_ipv6(
            $chunks[0],
            $chunks[1],
            $chunks[2],
            $chunks[3]
        );
    } else {
        return $str;
    }
}

/**
 * Return a "pure" IPv6 address printable string representation
 * of the ::/96 address indicated by the 4 8-bit "zones" of an
 * IPv4 address (e.g. (254, 239, 24, 134) -> ::feef:1886).
 */
function ipv4_zones_to_ipv6($q1, $q2, $q3, $q4) {
    if ($q1 == 0) {
        if ($q2 == 0) {
            if ($q3 == 0) {
                if ($q4 == 0) {
                    return '::0';
                } else {
                    return '::' . self::inflate_hexbit_pair($q4);
                }
            } else {
                return '::' . self::inflate_hex_word($q3, $q4);
            }
        } else {
            return '::' . self::inflate_hexbit_pair($q2) . ':' . self::inflate_hex_word($q3, $q4);
        }
    } else {
        return '::' . self::inflate_hex_word($q1, $q2) . ':' . self::inflate_hex_word($q3, $q4);
    }
}

/**
 * Convert two 8-bit IPv4 "zones" into a single 16-bit hexword,
 * stripping leading 0s as needed, e.g.:
 * (254, 239) -> feef
 * (0,1) -> 1
 */
function inflate_hex_word($hb1, $hb2) {
    $w = self::inflate_hexbit_pair($hb1) . self::inflate_hexbit_pair($hb2);
    return ltrim($w, '0');
}

/**
 * Convert one 8-bit IPv4 "zone" into two hexadecimal digits,
 * (hexits) padding with a leading zero if necessary, e.g.:
 * 254 -> fe
 * 2 -> 02
 */
function inflate_hexbit_pair($hb) {
    return str_pad(dechex($hb), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Although arguably *much* less elegant than the _inet_ntop() function proposed by JC Sama, it runs about 25% faster over my (essentially random) test cases.